# To find monthly average ndre and ndvi values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, mean

So, I have this data,

```
data = {
    'farm_Id': ['farm_258', 'farm_344', 'farm_345', 'farm_346', 'farm_348'],
    '2018-12-16_NDRE': [0.406, 0.380, 0.449, 0.432, 0.407],
    '2018-12-16_NDVI': [0.581, 0.552, 0.619, 0.573, 0.549],
    '2018-12-21_NDRE': [0.417, 0.270, 0.387, 0.403, 0.377],
    '2018-12-21_NDVI': [0.605, 0.416, 0.567, 0.555, 0.532],
    '2018-12-26_NDRE': [0.338, 0.191, 0.267, 0.252, 0.219],
    '2018-12-26_NDVI': [0.480, 0.285, 0.381, 0.324, 0.308],
    '2018-12-31_NDRE': [0.411, 0.202, 0.411, 0.463, 0.345],
    '2018-12-31_NDVI': [0.592, 0.294, 0.588, 0.622, 0.508],
    '2019-01-05_NDRE': [0.378, 0.207, 0.431, 0.495, 0.321],
    '2019-01-05_NDVI': [0.576, 0.293, 0.621, 0.668, 0.432],
}
```

I'm trying to find the monthly average values for ndre and ndvi.

So far have tried the following code.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index('farm_Id', inplace=True)
# Extract the month from column names
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns, format='%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
# Group by month and calculate the mean
monthly_average = df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).mean()
# Print the result
monthly_average
```

But, there is a format error for date (Error: time data "2018-12-16_NDRE" at position 0 doesn't match format specified). No matter how I try unable to fix the error and achive result. Please suggest the right method.

Comment: Have you checked the docs for expected formats? Especially, how do you expect to_datetime to interpret "_NDRE" or "_NDVI" ? (https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) You might need to crop the columns names prior to calling to_datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `pd.melt` to get your dataframe in vertical schema, then use `str.split` to separate the types (in your case NDVI and NDRE) and the date.
then you filter by type (since you want data related only to NDRE and NDVI) and you do a usual groupby and get the mean value.
**Approach1::** here is a sample code using your sample dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'farm_Id': ['farm_258', 'farm_344', 'farm_345', 'farm_346', 'farm_348'],
    '2018-12-16_NDRE': [0.406, 0.380, 0.449, 0.432, 0.407],
    '2018-12-16_NDVI': [0.581, 0.552, 0.619, 0.573, 0.549],
    '2018-12-21_NDRE': [0.417, 0.270, 0.387, 0.403, 0.377],
    '2018-12-21_NDVI': [0.605, 0.416, 0.567, 0.555, 0.532],
    '2018-12-26_NDRE': [0.338, 0.191, 0.267, 0.252, 0.219],
    '2018-12-26_NDVI': [0.480, 0.285, 0.381, 0.324, 0.308],
    '2018-12-31_NDRE': [0.411, 0.202, 0.411, 0.463, 0.345],
    '2018-12-31_NDVI': [0.592, 0.294, 0.588, 0.622, 0.508],
    '2019-01-05_NDRE': [0.378, 0.207, 0.431, 0.495, 0.321],
    '2019-01-05_NDVI': [0.576, 0.293, 0.621, 0.668, 0.432],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

results = (
    df
    .melt(id_vars='farm_Id')
    .assign(
        typee = lambda df_: df_['variable'].str.split('_').str[1],
        variable = lambda df_: df_['variable'].str.split('_').str[0]
    )
    .astype({'typee': 'category', 'variable': 'datetime64[ns]'})
    .rename(columns={'variable': 'date'})
    .query('typee.isin(["NDRE", "NDVI"])')
    .groupby(['date', 'typee'])
    .value.mean()
    .to_frame()
)
results.head(10)
```

**Approach2::** Following your proposed approach in the comments, you could complete your solution as follows (a `pd.rename` would resolve the columns naming after obtaining the results you need):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df.set_index('farm_Id', inplace=True) 
multi_columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(col.split('_')[0], col.split('_')[1]) for col in df.columns])
df.columns = multi_columns
result = (
    df
    .unstack(level=0)
    .reset_index()
    .groupby(['level_0', 'level_1'])
    [0].mean()
    .to_frame()
)
result
```

> ***NOTE:*** level_0 and level_1 are the date and type after extraction.

This will get you the following output in both cases:

| Date | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-12-16 | NDRE | 0.4148 |
|  | NDVI | 0.5748 |
| 2018-12-21 | NDRE | 0.3708 |
|  | NDVI | 0.5350 |
| 2018-12-26 | NDRE | 0.2534 |
|  | NDVI | 0.3556 |
| 2018-12-31 | NDRE | 0.3664 |
|  | NDVI | 0.5208 |
| 2019-01-05 | NDRE | 0.3664 |
|  | NDVI | 0.5180 |

I hope this helps!

Comment: I did try to restructure dataframe earlier as follows, similar to what you suggest, but arranged differently:

`import pandas as pd`
`df = pd.DataFrame(data)`
`df.set_index('Farm_Id', inplace=True)`
`multi_columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(col.split('_')[0], col.split('_')[1]) for col in df.columns])`
`df.columns = multi_columns`
`df`

Going ahead from here I have challenges in extracting monthly averages.

Comment: I see what you are trying to achieve, I edited my answer to have both approaches, I hope this helps!

Comment: .unstack() was a bit new to me. But I'm able to understand your approach. I see that it gives the mean NDVI and NDRE of all farms on a given date (`date --> ndvi, ndre ---> mean ndvi, ndre of all 6 farms`). 

But, I need the statistics per farm and per month. Basically, the mean has to be calculated row-wise and then month-wise with in this row for each of ndvi and ndre. 

Wish I could share a table here. But this is the skeleton I have in mind given one farm: 
`farm_258 --> Dec 2018 ndvi, Jan 2019 ndvi, Dec 2018 ndre, Jan 2019 ndre`

Comment: shouldn't adding 'farm_Id' to the groupby solve your issue? 
what do you mean by 'the mean has to be calculated row-wise'? what difference does it make to you since you have now the columns in this format: (Dec 2018 ndvi, Jan 2019 ndvi, Dec 2018 ndre, Jan 2019 ndre), while the `pd.unstack` is transforming the data, so adding 'farm_Id' to your groupby should fix your issue!

Comment: Yes, adding 'farm_Id' solved the issue. Since I was looking to aggregate over month, slightly modified the lambda function for `variable`. Now I have ndvi and ndre aggregated over each month for each farm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Posting the solution I could have. Thanks to `@Ali Massoud`.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'farm_Id': ['farm_258', 'farm_344', 'farm_345', 'farm_346', 'farm_348'],
    '2018-12-16_NDRE': [0.406, 0.380, 0.449, 0.432, 0.407],
    '2018-12-16_NDVI': [0.581, 0.552, 0.619, 0.573, 0.549],
    '2018-12-21_NDRE': [0.417, 0.270, 0.387, 0.403, 0.377],
    '2018-12-21_NDVI': [0.605, 0.416, 0.567, 0.555, 0.532],
    '2018-12-26_NDRE': [0.338, 0.191, 0.267, 0.252, 0.219],
    '2018-12-26_NDVI': [0.480, 0.285, 0.381, 0.324, 0.308],
    '2018-12-31_NDRE': [0.411, 0.202, 0.411, 0.463, 0.345],
    '2018-12-31_NDVI': [0.592, 0.294, 0.588, 0.622, 0.508],
    '2019-01-05_NDRE': [0.378, 0.207, 0.431, 0.495, 0.321],
    '2019-01-05_NDVI': [0.576, 0.293, 0.621, 0.668, 0.432],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

results = (
    df.melt(id_vars='farm_Id')
        .assign(
        typee = lambda df_: df_['variable'].str.split('_').str[1],
        variable = lambda df_: pd.to_datetime(df_['variable'].str.split('_').str[0]).dt.strftime('%b-%Y')
    )
     .astype({'typee': 'category'})
     .rename(columns={'variable': 'date'})
    .query('typee.isin(["NDRE", "NDVI"])')
    .groupby(['farm_Id', 'date', 'typee']).value.mean()
    .to_frame()
)
results = results.unstack(level = -1).unstack(level = -1)
results
```

Unsure if I could unstack() like this, but it does the job now.